# 14.04 Resetting Ubuntu startup settings?

Tags: 14.04, boot, gui

When I first installed Ubuntu dual-boot I would boot the computer and select Ubuntu 14.04, and a terminal would just flash with my username and take me to the logon screen, everything running smooth.
Yesterday I tried setting-up dual monitors on different graphics cards, one integrated and the other one being separate (GeForce GT 240) but it seems it didn't work out, the VGA cable was not working.
Anyway, since then when I select Ubuntu on boot-up, a purple screeen shows up with terminal-font 'Ubuntu' in the center and stays there for seconds, then my logon screen flashes, screen goes dark for couple of seconds and it reappears and then everything goes back to normal.
I don't understand what causes this, would it be the GUI startup? I'm afraid if it digs deep enough it could mess-up my whole GUI.
Do you have the same change? Know what it is?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry that's normal grub loader interface, as far as for your login screen flash it is because Ubuntu machine is loading and reading files and blinks like flash, during that flash you sometimes see some commands running in background and same happens during shutdown.
In the sum of all you don't worry that's all normal.

Comment: Thanks, being a (kind of) newbie to anything concerning graphic rendering and grub etc., I was worried that it could engender more stuff, just needed a confirmation that nothing's really up.